# sliced list encapsulated in "tuple", how to get list elems out and print?

Tags: python, list, parameters, tuples, slice

for example, I have a function print_members() that should print the 2 params passed in, the name of the given group and the names of the members of the group:

```
def print_members(group_name, *member_names):
    print("Members of", group_name)

    for i in range(len(member_names)):
        print(member_names[i])
```

and in main() I create a list that needs to be printed with the function where the first element of the list is group_name and the rest are names of members of the group. To do this I run the following in main()

```
def main():
    group_mates = ["Book Club", "Allen", "Karla", "Matt", "Nadia"]
    print_members(group_mates[0], group_mates[1:])
```

however when this runs it (afaik) passes the second param as a tuple of one element, the sliced list, so when it goes through the for-loop, it only sees one element, the encapsulated sliced list. like this:

```
(['Allen', 'Karla', 'Matt', 'Nadia'])
```

so it prints:

```
Members of Book Club
['Allen', 'Karla', 'Matt', 'Nadia']
```

even though it should be

```
Members of Book Club
Allen
Karla
Matt
Nadia
```

is there perhaps another way to call the function print_members() in main() so it doesn't encapsulate the sliced list in a tuple? or is there a better way of writing print_members() ? the function also needs to be able to take in an arbitrary number of group member names following the first param, hence the asterisk, and print it the same way as I want it to print the tuple of a single list, so I can't flatten the list after I get it as a param. doing so would (again afaik) flatten a list that is already a 1d list, making each *character* its own element in the list. I need each *name* as its own element. any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does your function, `print_members` have the `*` in the argument: `*member_names`?  This signifies *args: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3.  If you remove the `*` your function does what you want it to do.  A list is already mutable, meaning that it can already be varied in length and number of elements, the `*` means that the number of lists could vary.

Comment: Also, I recommend finding another object type besides a list to solve this problem.  I would look into using a python dictionary.

Comment: @DavidJohnColemanII the function needs to be able to take names as comma-separated arguments as well not just as a list with group name and member names

Comment: for example, like `print_members("Book Club", "Allen", "Karla", "Matt", "Nadia")` as well, that's why there's an asterisk in the argument

Comment: sorry I didn't make that explicit. and I'd prefer to stick to using lists because that's what I am trying to learn

Comment: See my comment in answer by @ReblochonMasque about how to handle variadic arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you unpacking the parameter `member_names` in `print_members`?

```
def print_members(group_name, member_names):  # <-- here
    print("Members of", group_name)

    for i in range(len(member_names)):
        print(member_names[i])

def main():
    group_mates = ["Book Club", "Allen", "Karla", "Matt", "Nadia"]
    print_members(group_mates[0], group_mates[1:])

main()
```

#### output:

```
Members of Book Club
Allen
Karla
Matt
Nadia
```

#### Alternative data structure:

As suggested by @DavidJohnColemanII, you could map the club with a collection of its members using a dictionary:

```
group_mates = {"Book Club": ["Allen", "Karla", "Matt", "Nadia"]}
```

and iterate over the keys and values to print:

```
for group, members in group_mates.items():
    print(f"Members of {group}:", end='\n')
    for member in members:
        print(member)
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I would have added a suggestion to use a different object type besides the list.  I think a hashtable/ `dict` would work better for what the OP appears to be trying to solve.

Comment: good point, I added to the answer, thank you for the suggested improvement.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque apologies I didn't make myself clear. the function should be able to take names as comma-separated arguments as well, not just as a list with group name and member names. so it should be able to take in `print_members("Book Club", "Allen", "Karla", "Matt", "Nadia")` and print the same. I'd rather use lists as that is what I'm trying to learn

Comment: If you want your function to take args as such: `print_members("Book Club", "Allen", "Karla", "Matt", "Nadia")`, then this is a matter of learning how `*args and **kwargs` functions.  You can read up on that here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3.  Your function prototype would be: `def print_members(*args):`.  `group_name = args[0]`, `member_names = args[1:]` <- This will be a tuple, turn it into a list with `list()`

Comment: If you want to add the option to take input arguments that could be a list vs. various strings, you need to add logic that checks the length of args: `len(args)` and the type of args: `type(args[0]).__name__` in that order.